# Let f be a convex differentiable function. Prove that if u is any continuous function, then ...

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f$ be a convex differentiable function. Prove that if $u$ is any continuous function, then $$\frac1 a \int_0^a f(u(t))dt \geq f \bigg(\frac1a \int_0^a u(t) dt\bigg) $$

I **need** insight on this please.

Comment: What do you mean by convex? downwards or upwards?

Comment: I'm not sure. How much does that matter in the question? I'm not even sure how to approach it.

Comment: @Vim. The opposite of convex is concave. Thus he is referring to the fact that for all $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ in the domain of $f$, $f(tx_{1}+(1-t)x_{2})) \leq tf(x_{1}) + (1-t)f(x_{2})$

Comment: I feel it may have something to do with Jensen's Inequality. Which goes like this: If $f(x)$ is defined on $[a,b]$ and $f''(x)\ge 0$ (downwards convex), then $\forall x_1, x_2 \in [a,b]$, $\lambda f(x_1)+(1-\lambda) f(x_2) \ge f(\lambda x_1 +(1-\lambda) x_2), \forall \lambda \in [0,1]$

Comment: @GustavoMontano  yeah I know that. But sometimes I'm just confused with these two words. Could you please tell me which one means $f''(x) \ge 0$ and which one the opposite?

Comment: @Vim. I get confused too! Through elementary school I used the notion of "Concave Up" and "Concave Down" to get through this. I found out the other day that there is a simpler way. Convex := Smiley Face. Concave := Sad Face. :D

Comment: The cleverest I've ever seen! thumbs up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since $f$ is convex differentiable ,
so 
$$f(u(t))\ge f(x_{0})+f'(x_{0})(u(t)-x_{0})$$
let $$x_{0}=\dfrac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{a}u(t)dt$$
so
$$f(u(t))\ge f\left(\dfrac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{a}u(t)dt\right)+f'\left(\dfrac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{a}u(t)dt\right)\left[u(t)-\dfrac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{a}u(t)dt\right]$$
Note
$$\int_{0}^{a}\left[u(t)-\dfrac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{a}u(t)dt\right]dt=\int_{0}^{a}u(t)dt-\int_{0}^{a}u(t)dt=0$$
so
$$\int_{0}^{a}f(u(t))dt\ge \int_{0}^{a}f\left(\dfrac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{a}u(t)dt\right)+0$$
so
$$\dfrac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{a}f(u(t))dt\ge f\left(\dfrac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{a}u(t)dt\right)$$

Comment: Why is $\int_{0}^{a}\left[u(t)-\dfrac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{a}u(t)dt\right]dt=\int_{0}^{a}u(t)dt-\int_{0}^{a}u(t)dt$ true?

Comment: because $\dfrac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{a}u(t)dt$ is constant,so $$\int_{0}^{a}\left(\dfrac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{a}u(t)dt\right)dt=\int_{0}^{a}u(t)\int_{0}^{a}     \dfrac{1}{a}dt=\int_{0}^{a}u(t)dt$$

Comment: how do you get from $$\int_{0}^{a}f(u(t))dt\ge \int_{0}^{a}f\left(\dfrac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{a}u(t)dt\right)+0$$ to $$\dfrac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{a}f(u(t))dt\ge f\left(\dfrac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{a}u(t)dt\right)$$ ?